# django distinct queryset from queryset-values

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, distinct

I have a `User` that can have multiple `Account`s. There can be multiple `Unit`s on each `Account`.
I build a filter dictionary and get relevant units:

```
units = Unit.objects.filter(**unit_filter)
```

However, I would also like to get distinct users. I can easily get their ids:

```
user_dicts = units.values('account__user').distinct()
```

or to be more exact:

```
user_ids = [rec.get('account__user') for rec in 
            units.values('account__user').distinct()]
```

So then I can filter Users using `User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)`. (I can also use the generator expression instead of list comprehension, but that is not the point.)

I am not sure but evaluating `id in` seems to me not very efficient. Is there a better way how to get unique users from filtered units?

---

Edit:

I add SQL queries (did not test them, may be wrong) to make obvious what I am trying to do in Django ORM. Actually I am trying to use `JOIN` instead of `WHERE` clause.

I hope for this:

```
WITH selected_units AS
  (SELECT id, account_id FROM units)
SELECT DISTINCT u.id FROM user u 
  JOIN account a on a.user_id=u.id
  JOIN unit ut ON ut.account=a.id 
  JOIN selected_units s ON s.id=ut.id;
```

But with `id_in` I get this:

```
WITH selected_units AS
  (SELECT id, account_id FROM units)
SELECT DISTINCT u.id FROM user u 
  JOIN account a on a.user_id=u.id 
  JOIN unit ut ON ut.account_id=a.id 
WHERE ut.id IN (SELECT id FROM selected_units);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using subqueries, something like this:

```
User.objects.filter(account__unit__in=units)
```

Or less pretty:

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=units.values_list('account__user__id', flat=True))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I used `values_list()` in the past and did not realize I can use `flat=True` and then `distinct()`. However, there is always this `id in` test, although it looks a little neater. I added sql queries to the question to make more obvious what I am trying to do.